# Afinal, "obedecer" é verbo transitivo direto ou indireto?"

Tags: verbos, regência

O meu **"Aurélio"** cita como transitivo indireto ou intransitivo.  O [**Priberam**](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/obedecer) cita como transitivo ou intransitivo e seus exemplos são do uso como **transitivo indireto**. No entanto, ouço com frequência "as ordens não foram obedecidas" inclusive no Português escrito, como no livro [**Chaves da Minha Vida**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=vn5JBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA144&lpg=PA144&dq=as+ordens+n%C3%A3o+foram+obedecidas&source=bl&ots=ZL1a_sPELc&sig=GGE0loPx7_IH1bV1W7hjl7ZhZ6w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAmoVChMItrq1qZ-7xwIVhoWQCh04TgZb#v=onepage&q=as%20ordens%20n%C3%A3o%20foram%20obedecidas&f=false) de Rui Carvalho:

- **"Para espanto do Ministro, as ordens não foram obedecidas"**

Todos nós sabemos, no entanto, que verbos transitivos indiretos não vão para a voz passiva. Afinal, "obedecer" é transitivo direto e indireto, além de intransitivo?

Comment: Pelo que estou vendo, algum dia ele já foi transitivo direto, e a voz passiva sobreviveu. Mas está difícil achar uma boa fonte que explique isso direito.

Comment: Pode bem já ter sido transitivo direto. Mas pode ser também simplesmente uma "inovação." É fácil, mesmo em livros, dizer coisas como "as ordens não foram obedecidas," talvez por analogia com _cumprir, acatar, respeitar_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alguns gramáticos aceitam a regência direta do verbo *obedecer*, outros não, mas todos aceitam a voz passiva. A aceitação da regência direta advém do seu uso por alguns autores antigos.

Isto é bem explicado no [Dicionário de Verbos e Regimes de Francisco Fernandes](http://www.livrariacultura.com.br/p/dicionario-de-verbos-e-regimes-75889) (gentilmente disponibilizado por Bfavaretto). Na entrada *obedecer*, acerca da regência direta vem:

> *Não obstante condenado por alguns autores de boa nota, é comum encontrar-se nos clássicos antigos o verbo OBEDECER construído com objeto direto*: “Tudo o que o Senhor tem falado faremos e OBEDECEREMOS.” ([João F. ]Almeida, *Êxodo*, 24, 7.) (…) “Quem me ama (diz Cristo) OBEDECERÁ e guardará meus preceitos.” ( [Padre António Vieira, *Sermões*] VII, 160.) *Com a voz passiva, porém, é construção universalmente aceita*: “A ordem foi OBEDECIDA.”

Ambos os autores citados nesta passagem são do século XVII.

Já o [Professor Paulo Fernandes](http://www.paulohernandes.pro.br/dicas/001/dica039.html) não se limita a descrever a posição dos outros e, citando o Dicionário prático de regência verbal de Celso P. Luft, afirma que *obedecer* "pode ser usado na regência direta - *obedecer alguém* - ou indireta - *obedecer a alguém*."

A [InfoEscola](http://www.infoescola.com/portugues/regencia-verbal/), que diz que *obedecer* é transitivo indireto mas que pode ser usado na voz passiva! "A fila não foi obedecida."

Para mim pessoalmente, valha isso o que valer, "obedecer um comando" ou o "comando foi obedecido" não me choca, mas "obedecer o comandante!?" Acho que precisaria dalgum tempo para me habituar.

Comment: O [verbete do Luft](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ttsq.jpg), caso interesse. Dá exemplos, mas não discute a origem das regências.

Comment: Fenomenal! Como é que descobriste isto?

Comment: Eu tenho o dicionário e tirei uma foto :)

Comment: Na verdade eu me confundi, o que tenho e fotografei é o [Dicionário de verbos e regimes](http://www.livrariacultura.com.br/p/dicionario-de-verbos-e-regimes-75889) de Francisco Fernandes.

Comment: Obrigado na mesma. Se reparares, em quase todos os exemplos, a regência direta facilita a construção da frase. Por exemplo, "Quem me ama obedecerá e guardará meus preceitos" é mais escorreito que "... obedecerá aos meus preceitos e guarda-los-á." Acho que ainda não podemos dizer como os ingleses "... obedecerá a e guardará meus preceitos." Talvez usassem regência direta por conveniência.

Comment: "é transitivo direto mas pode ser usado na voz passiva!"    Jacinto, você quis mesmo dizer transitivo "direto"?  Não seria "indireto"?

Comment: @Centaurus Seria pois! C' um raio. E vai já ser.

Answer (score -1):

TRANSITIVO INDIRETO:
Obedecer A um comando, obedecer AO comandante.
A regra é clara, necessita da preposição "A".

Parece que tem pessoas que não entenderam direito (basta ler algumas respostas anteriores)!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).