# Li recentemente que "O Lobo de Wall Street foi o filme mais assistido em 2014" Estaria correto?

Tags: voz-passiva, transitividade-verbal

During a short flight back home, I picked up a magazine and started reading: "O Lobo de Wall Street foi um dos filmes mais assistidos em 2014."  I've posted a question a while ago (["obedecer é verbo transitivo direto ou indireto?"](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/954/afinal-obedecer-%C3%A9-verbo-transitivo-direto-ou-indireto)) and here I am again asking a similar question: when I was a student, more years ago than I care to count, I was taught that "quem assiste, assiste a alguma coisa" unless the meaning of "assistir" is "to assist or help". If a preposition is required, it is considered "verbo transitivo indireto". I was also taught back then that "transitivos indiretos" cannot be put into the passive voice. Have things changed?

**EM PORTUGUÊS**
Durante uma curta viagem aérea, comecei a folhear uma revista e li: "O Lobo de Wall Street foi um dos filmes mais assistidos em 2014."  Há algum tempo postei a pergunta ["obedecer é verbo transitivo direto ou indireto?"](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/954/afinal-obedecer-%C3%A9-verbo-transitivo-direto-ou-indireto) e agora faço uma pergunta semelhante: quando estudante, há muitos anos, aprendi que "quem assiste, assiste a alguma coisa" exceto se o sentido for "ajudar" ("o médico assistiu o doente"). Sendo necessário o uso de preposição, o verbo é transitivo indireto. Se o verbo é transitivo indireto, não poderia ir para a voz passiva. Não sendo esse o primeiro exemplo que encontro, pergunto: mudaram as regras?

Comment: Piada obrigatória: [XXX](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0295701) nem sequer é de 2013!!

Comment: Eu consigo entender "A Etiópia foi o país mais assistido pela Unicef em 2014."  mas não "XXX foi o filme mais assistido".  Certamente, aceitaria "o filme mais visto, mais exibido, mais comentado, etc, ou até mesmo "de maior bilheteria".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As recomendações que encontrei online divergem. A [InfoEscola](http://www.infoescola.com/portugues/regencia-verbal/) e a [Educação uol](http://educacao.uol.com.br/dicas-portugues/verbo-assistir-resiste-como-transitivo-indireto.jhtm) não admitem a regência direta ou voz passiva de *assistir* no sentido de ver, que é o relevante aqui (admitem-no apenas no sentido de ajudar). Já o [manual de redação da Pontífica Universidade Católica da Rio Grande do Sul](http://www.pucrs.br/manualred/regverbal.php), baseando-se em nomes grandes como [Celso Luft](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celso_Luft) tolera a regência direta e voz passiva, e dá precisamente como exemplo *assistir o filme* e *o filme foi assistido*.

O [manual de redação da PUCRS](http://www.pucrs.br/manualred/regverbal.php) evita a dicotomia certo versus errado, em favor de uma abordagem com mais gradações: preferível, tolerável, grosseiro, inadmissível, com mais algumas pelo meio. A posição de Luft, como transmitida pelo manual, é que o mais que se pode é aconselhar a sintaxe original, tradicional (regência direta).

Ao contrário do que se passa com o verbo *obedecer*, não encontrei registo de uso da regência direta de *assistir* entre os autores clássicos. Esta regência parece ser um inovação relativamente recente, e comum a alguns outros verbos. O [manual de redação da PUCRS](http://www.pucrs.br/manualred/regverbal.php) apresenta vários exemplos. Estas inovações começam por ocorrer na linguagem coloquial, mas tem já vindo a ser adotadas por alguns escritores.

Answer (score 6):

http://www.migalhas.com.br/Gramatigalhas/10,MI80436,91041-Voz+passiva+quando+e+possivel

13) Quanto a esses verbos que mudam de transitividade conforme o sentido, fixa-se-lhes a regra de que apenas admitem transposição para a voz passiva quando são transitivos diretos: I) "O cliente foi assistido pelo advogado" (admite emprego na voz passiva, porque, no sentido de auxiliar, o verbo assistir é transitivo direto); II) "O espetáculo foi assistido pelo advogado" (exemplo equivocado e errôneo, já que, sendo transitivo indireto nesse sentido, o verbo assistir não admite transposição para a voz passiva).

Acho que cada vez mais, e especialmente na indústria de entretenimento, as regras formais de escrita são deixadas de lado.